# Filling the Combobox with choices

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

I'm just a complete beginner when it comes to programming or java.
So for the start my plan was to create a window useing JavaFX(combined with scene builder) where I do have a button that leads me to another window where i do have a combobox. I googled for hours now to find a way to fill that combobox with choices but all the solutions i found don't work for me. Thats why I think I made some mistakes here and I hope you can somehow help me. Or at list give me a hint what I should learn/read to get to the solution myself. 
So to start with, here's my main.java code where I build my first stage.

main.java:

```java
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene-Hauptmenu.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Fishbase");
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
}
```

In my "Scene-Hauptmenu.fxml" all that matters is the button that leads me to my second window:

Scene-Hauptmenu.fxml:

```java
<Button id="btn_gefangen" fx:id="btn_gefangen" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#gefangen" text="Ich habe Fische gefangen!" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
```

So far everything works fine and I can switch to my second window without a problem. But I think my main problem lies within my controller class so here it is.

MyController.java:

```java
public class MyController implements Initializable{
    private Node node;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
    private Parent root;

    @FXML
    private Button btn_gefangen;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> chobo_fisch; 

    @FXML
    private Button btn_gefangen_zurueck;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    public void gefangen(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        node = (Node) event.getSource();
        stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        scene = stage.getScene();

        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("gefangen.fxml"));

        root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        scene.setRoot(root);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.setTitle("Fische eintragen");          
    }


    public void gefangen_zurueck(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        node = (Node) event.getSource();
        stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        scene = stage.getScene();
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("Scene-Hauptmenu.fxml"));
        root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        scene.setRoot(root);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.setTitle("Fishbase");     
    }   
}
```

So the button "btn_gefangen" leads me to that other window where i do have the combobox with the fx:id "chobo_fisch".

gefangen.fxml:

```java
<ComboBox fx:id="chobo_Fisch" prefWidth="150.0"/>
```

So I googled for hours but I still didnt find any solution to fill the combobox with choices that works with my code. What did I do wrong? Can anyone help me here?

Best regards

Jannik

Comment: Why are you declaring only fields, not local variables?There's no point in keeping data in fields,if there is no need to access it later.In fact this increases the footprint of your class in addition to making some of the objects unavailable for garbage collection,even if they are no longer needed.Furthermore I recommend using different controller classes for different fxmls.The approach for controller specifying the controller that beginners most often start with(fx:controller)results in one controller instance being created every time a fxml is loaded.No nodes from different fxmls available.

Answer (score 3):

I found three variants, depending on your setup:

## 1st variant

```
// Weekdays 
String week_days[] = 
    { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
      "Thrusday", "Friday" }; 

// Create a combo box 
ComboBox combo_box = new ComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(week_days));
```

(Soure: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javafx-combobox-with-examples/)

## 2nd variant

```
final ComboBox emailComboBox = new ComboBox();
emailComboBox.getItems().addAll(
            "jacob.smith@example.com",
            "isabella.johnson@example.com",
            "ethan.williams@example.com",
            "emma.jones@example.com",
            "michael.brown@example.com"  
        );
```

Source: (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm)

## 3rd variant (for FXML)

```
<ComboBox fx:id="someName">
     <items>
         <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="1"/>
              <String fx:value="2"/>
              <String fx:value="3"/>
              <String fx:value="4"/>
          </FXCollections>
      </items>
      <value>
           <String fx:value="1"/>
      </value>
</ComboBox>
```

**Edit**

As mentioned by fabian you should make sure to include the FXML imports:

```
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
```

The second one may not be needed.

Comment: When I try your 3rd variant i get the following error: Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: FXCollections is not a valid type.
/D:/workspace/Fishbase/bin/application/gefangen.fxml:33

Comment: @JannikVöhl You need to make sure to include the proper import processing instructtions at the start of the fxml file: `<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?> <?import java.lang.String?>` (The second one may already be covered by an import for `java.lang.*`)

Comment: Oh my... I thought i did write the import line for that already but I actually didn't. I'm sorry, it works perfectly now, thank you so much and sorry for my stupid questions!

Comment: First there are no stupid questions :) Second I would suggest to use a good IDE that adds these imports for you, like IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition), Netbeans or Eclipse. All are free.

Comment: I do use Eclipse, yet it doesn't suggest imports on FXML files, at least for me not :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to those stuff but I think this is how it should look or at least close too if I understood what you wanted. 
 Example below:

`ComboBox<String> stuff = new ComboBox<>();
          stuff.getItems().addAll("1","2","5","10");`

Note: I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.add("a");
    items.add("b");
    chobo_fisch.getItems().addAll(items);
```

Comment: Sadly I only get a java.lang.NullPointerException with that

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox must be filled with items (in your case String):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    chobo_fisch.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(list));
```

If you use a combobox of a more complex object, you could use a cellfactory to choose the value that is displayed :

```
    chobo_fisch.setCellFactory(obj -> new ChoboFischListCell());
    chobo_fisch.setButtonCell(new ChoboFischListCell());
```

where ChoboFischListCell is a class that extends ListCell and where you implement which field of your object should be displayed.